# Merge 2 existing php functions into one

Tags: php

I have two PHP functions that work great independently on seperate php pages.

Page one:

```
<?php
 function shortURL($url) {
 $ch = curl_init();
 $timeout = 5;
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,'http://tinyurl.com/api-create.php?url='.$url);
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);
 $short_url = curl_exec($ch);
 curl_close($ch);
 return $short_url;
 }
$url = "http://technoflirt.com/tech/2011/01/11/running-php-script-host/";
 $short_url = shortURL($url);
 echo "Actual url =". $url . "<br />";
 echo "Shortened url = <a href=$short_url>$short_url</a>  <br />"; 
?>
```

Page two is an existing snippet that emails information.  I've tried to combine the functions with no luck where I've pasted the function shortURL($url) above the function email() and then pasted the $url and $short_url and changed the echo statements to $message.  This results in a fatal error: PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function shortURL() so I know that does not work.  How do I successfully convert the tinyURL and then incorporate it into the function email?

```
     function shortURL($url) {
        $ch = curl_init();
        $timeout = 5;
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,'http://tinyurl.com/api-create.php?url='.$url);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);
        $short_url = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $short_url;    

    function email($array, $task, $techinfo,$additionalinfo = array()) {
            $to = $techinfo["EmpHTEmail"];   
            $url = "http://technoflirt.com/tech/2011/01/11/running-php-script-host/";
            $short_url = shortURL($url);
            $subject = ($task == "unschedule") ? '' : ($task == "notify" ? "": "Else Message");
            $message = "";  
                if($task == "unschedule")
                    $message .="Work Order #:" . $array[0]["WorkOrderNum"] . " is cancelled.";
                elseif($task == "notify")
                   {    
                   $message .="".$additionalinfo[0]['sShortName']." (" . $array[0]["WorkOrderNum"] . ") <BR>".$additionalinfo[0]['sAddressNum']." ".$additionalinfo[0]['sAddressLine1'].", ".$additionalinfo[0]['sCityName']."<BR>".$additionalinfo[0]['sPhone1'] . " - ".$_SESSION['Latitude'].",".$_SESSION['Longitude']."<BR>";
                   $message .="". $additionalinfo[0]['JobDescription'] . " - ". $url . "";
                   $message .="Actual url =". $url . "";
                   $message .="Shortened url = $short_url"; 
                   }

                   $message .="";

                // Always set content-type when sending HTML email
                $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
                $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

               mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you do just have used the command inside the other function without having access to the function because it is in another file.

Just copy the complete function above the mail function in the same file.

But you should maybe collect all separate loose functions in one big file and include this in all pages to gain access whenever you need anything.

e.g. functions.php

and in your pages you would then just include this file.

```
include "PATH/TO/FILE/functions.php";
```

Comment: I did ...I updated the second code block...this is what I did to merge the two files and it is giving me a problem.

Answer (score 0):

The function email() was part of a much larger class called Communications.  I placed the function shortURL() outside of this class directly above it at the top of the file and it worked fine.